# TensorFlow gradient does not respond when using while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow to build a deep learning model. (The entire model is very complicated.) In the model, I need to use `while_loop` to dynamically control the computation flow based on my input sentences number. Previously, I used `for` loop instead of `while_loop`. After I switched to `while_loop`, the gradient doesn't work any more.

By the gradient not working I mean that if I execute forward, it works fine (produces some output). But if I enable gradients computation for training, it doesn't produce any response when I run my code, just hangs there. In `top`, it shows as `S` (suspend).

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Below is how I use `while_loop`, in a very standard way:

```
def body(argmax_ep_gate, h, mem_state_previous, dummy):
  '''doing some computation'''
  return tf.to_int32(argmax_ep_gate), h, mem_state_current, mem_state_previous

def condition(argmax_ep_gate, h, mem_state_previous, dummy):
  '''return some condition in bool'''

argmax_g, h, _, state = tf.while_loop(
  condition, body, [initial_argmax_g, initial_h, self.state, self.state])
```

Comment: Thank you for modifying the grammar. Also, a issue has been reported to Tensorflow issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to [TensorFlow stuck into endless loop using tf.while_loop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571017/tensorflow-stuck-into-endless-loop-using-tf-while-loop). note that if the body contains trainable variables, you need use variable scope