# TensorFlow stuck into endless loop using tf.while_loop()

Tags: python, tensorflow

#### Steps to reproduce

I am using TensorFlow to implement a network that needs to use `tf.while_loop()`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
class model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.argmax_ep_gate_array = [ tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None]) for _ in range(10)]
        argmax_ep_gate_array_concat = tf.concat(0, self.argmax_ep_gate_array)
        story_len = tf.constant(7)
        starter = tf.constant(0)
        z = []
        def body(hops):
            hops = tf.add(hops,1)
            z.append(hops)
            return hops
        def condition(hops):
            return tf.logical_and(tf.less(tf.gather(argmax_ep_gate_array_concat, hops),story_len),tf.less(hops,tf.constant(20)))

        self.gate_index = tf.while_loop(condition,body,[starter])
        self.z=tf.concat(0,z)

    def step(self, sess):
        feed={}
        for i in range(10):
            feed[self.argmax_ep_gate_array[i].name]=[i]
        print (sess.run([self.gate_index,self.z],feed))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while_loop = model()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    while_loop.step(sess)
```

#### What have you tried?

I find that If I want to sess.run() any variable in the body() that is not returned, tensorflow would stuck into endless loop. 
The above example is trivial, but it reveals something. In the real case, I am using `tf.while_loop()` running a RNN which includes y= wx+b something like that, but the `w` and `b` are not returned after while loop. In the forward network, it works fine. However, if I run the back propagation, the program would stuck into endless loop. I suppose the code above reproducing my issue, because back propagation do need to modify `w` and `b`. Or is there any way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You cannot store tensors that were created in the loop body for later use, because that breaks some assumptions about how the loop is structured.

In general, the `condition()` and `body()` functions must not have side effects.
Indeed, it is unlikely that your program has the intended behavior: TensorFlow will execute the `body()` function *once*, to build the necessary graph structure, so `z` will only contain one element after running `model.__init__()`.

Instead, you must construct `z` incrementally in the loop body, using `tf.concat()` and producing the value as a loop variable:

```
starter = tf.constant(0)
z_initial = tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32)

def body(hops, z_prev):
    hops = tf.add(hops, 1)
    z_next = tf.concat(0, [z_prev, tf.expand_dims(hops, 0)])
    return hops, z_next
def condition(hops, z):
    return tf.logical_and(tf.less(tf.gather(
        argmax_ep_gate_array_concat, hops), story_len), tf.less(hops, tf.constant(20)))

self.gate_index, self.z = tf.while_loop(condition,body,[starter, z_initial])
```

Comment: Thanks. 3 more problems. 1. If `self.z=tf.concat(0,z)` gave error like `Nonetype` Error or just contained one value, I'm okay with the result, but in my example, the program just stuck. 2. My `body()` functions involve many trainable parameter, like weight, bias, cell. Do I need to send all of them into `body()` functions and return them? 3. `cell` is an object in TensorFlow, How to send an object into `body()`.

Comment: 1. Yes, this is regrettable. It would be worth finding a way to avoid this error. 2. The `body()` function can implicitly capture tensors and variables from the enclosing scope, so you can probably use this mechanism to get them into your loop. 3. I'm not sure what `cell` you're talking about, but you can probably use implicit capture here as well.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble using this method. The forward pass is fine, but when trying to compute the gradients, it seems that only one value (the last) is seen and I get this error: ValueError: Shapes (24, 4, 65) and (1, 4, 65) are not compatible. Is this expected?

Comment: @jstaker7, two things I am able to come up with are: 1. make sure your condition function run successfully at least once; 2. check your body function and make sure the integrity of your graph. Hope that would hlep.

Comment: @mrry I am having the same issue (landed here from the github issue page). I am using mocked components (`mock.Mock()`), could it be those stuff acting as a side effect?